# GPS module stops working, is unable to setMode to on

Tags: arduino

I have been using the GPS module on waspmotes, and I have been able to get data off it. However on a fine day, with clear visible skies(which I don't think matters), I cannot be able to set the power mode on.

On calling `GPS.setMode(GPS_ON)`, it fails to set the power mode on, and on freezes on subsequent call to: `gpsConnected = GPS.check();`

I have tried changing the GPS unit to no avail. I am using the following code. (NB: I have removed the unnecessary bits of code for the sake of brevity)

```cpp
void setup()
{
  ACC.ON();
  USB.begin();  // Opening UART to show messages using 'Serial Monitor'

  //Initialize the GPS module
  GPS.ON();  // Turn GPS on
  GPS.setMode(GPS_ON);    // set GPS on
  if(!GPS.pwrMode) USB.println("Was unable to set on the GPS internal power mode.");  //this message gets printed.
  if(!GPS.setCommMode(GPS_NMEA_GGA)) USB.println("Was unable to set the GPS communication mode.");

  // Power up the Real Time Clock(RTC), init I2C bus and read initial values
  RTC.ON();
  ........
}

void loop(){
  //declare the variables
  len, i, j = 0;
  char degree[4] = "", minutes[8] = "", *latitude, *longitude, *altitude;
  uint8_t temperature = 0;
  int8_t fileFound = 0;
  double latitude_dd, longitude_dd;
  byte accOk;

  //check if the GPS has connected to the satellite
  GPS.begin();  // open the uart
  GPS.init();  // Inits the GPS module
  gpsConnected = GPS.check();

  ........
  ........
}
```

What might have happened???

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by using the RTC.setTime function. In the code, as can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/RmA98MkD, on line 195, `RTC.setTimeFromGPS()`, I was setting the boards time with the time that I received from GPS. This ended up screwing the GPS connection up and the code only looped once. You can see detailed conversations from here: http://www.libelium.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=9861

Answer (score 0):

You Need to simple test.  First you ensure that you are giving TTl input to the Tx and rx pin . If you upload this program It will gives GPS output string.If you are using GPS module with Serial output of RS 232 out, As you said it wont work.IT expecting TTl input only

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin();
}
void loop()
{

}
```